# How to use sudo with rcp command to copy files from linux host to HP-UX host?

Tags: linux, bash, hp-ux

I'm having this issue where when I try to use sudo to rcp some files from a Linux host to an HP-UX host (note that the destination directory requires root access to write to), I get the following error from HP-UX's side:

```
remshd: Login incorrect.
```

I should note that the passwords for the Linux host and the HP-UX host are different. The command doesn't seem to give me a chance to enter the proper HP-UX password and automatically defaults to this error.

Comment: Is root login disabled?  Can you login as root locally (i.e., as a login shell), or ssh from root to root?

Comment: [Please do not cross post](http://superuser.com/questions/442392/how-to-use-sudo-with-rcp-command-to-copy-files-from-linux-host-to-hp-ux-host). Server Fault is the correct place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The [rcp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp) says

> Rcp does not prompt for passwords; it uses Kerberos authentication ...

You'll probably find it easier to use [scp](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1) to do this. If you allow root logins via ssh on ypor HPUX system then

```
scp -r /local/path root@hpux.tld:/remote/path
```

should do the trick. If you don't allow root logins then login to the HPUX host and obtain a root shell then

```
scp -r user@linux.tld:/remote/path /local/path
```